# Display PDF in a browser Only ONCE and delete it from server C#

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf

Currently we have an application which generates PDF and is loaded in a page directly in the Response Object. The original file is deleted off the temporary location, to avoid accessing the PDF again.

```
       MyFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;

        if (FileSize > 0)
        {
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
            MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
            MyFileStream.Close();

            // Delete the pdf file
            File.Delete(fileName);

            if (Buffer != null)
            {
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName);
                Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("File not found, or file is empty.");
            Response.Flush();
        }
```

I'd like to modify the page to have the PDF loaded in a DIV within the page, so that I can add another interactive element on the same page like a button to trigger something else.

I saw the way to embed the PDF is to use something like

```
<div class="pdf">
<object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
  No biggie... you can <a href="myfile.pdf">click here to
  download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
This is where I will have other links or buttons to trigger some functions.
</div>
```

However, this seems to point to a static PDF resource myfile.pdf from the server.

My question: **How can I make sure that the static PDF is not available for direct linking after this page was opened?**

( Similar to my original code where once the page was displayed and streamed to the Response Page, the static file is deleted)

Comment: What prevent you to simply point your actual page URL from the data attribute ?

Comment: Use request signing with a short TTL

Answer (score 0):

You can write an aspx page that writes the PDF content out as a byte stream to the requester. It would need to specify that the output type is application/pdf. For example if you have a page called `getpdf.aspx` it can accept a parameter of `pdf_id`. You can then reference that page with parameter value and it will load the pdf dynamically without it ever writing to the server file system.

Then in your application page you could have a div or iframe that references the `getpdf.aspx` page with the requested `pdf_id`:

```
<iframe src="getpdf.aspx?pdf_id=1234" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gmiley and Eric...

Based on your pointers , I did some more research and found what I was looking for... using embed or a free library to do what i needed.

```
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>PDF Documents</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/pdfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            console.log("Loading ObjectPDF");
            var pdf = new PDFObject({
                url: "<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Pages/GetPDF.aspx?PdfFileName=" + pdfFile)%>",
                id: "pdfRendered",
                pdfOpenParams: {
                    view: "FitH"
                }
            }).embed("pdfRendered");
            console.log("finished Embed");
            console.dir(pdf);
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="pdfRendered" style="height: 90%">
        <p>
            It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser. <a href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Pages/GetPDF.aspx?PdfFileName=" + pdfFile)%>">Click here to download the PDF file.</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="eSign" style="background: #ccc;">SIgnature Trigger here</div>
</body>
</html>
```